# How to disable the check-box in java-script depending on bit of the variable?

Tags: javascript, html, c

script and currently handling a code in HTMl.

Here is problem set :

I have around 32 checkboxes on my webpage, now when my page completely loads up I need to disable the checkboxes based on some variable say dis.

dis=15;

In binary form it will be 00001111, hence based on bit information i need to make my checkboxes enable and disable.

Any logic or method to do in JS will be appreciable.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>checkboxes Enable</title>
</head>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
function(value) {
}

</script>
<body onload="function()">

</body>
</html>
```

Consider that I am passing the value=8 to the function, So on this basis I need to enable the checkboxes named as "checkbox1","checkbox2"......."checkbox32". 8 in binary is 00001000....hence 4th  "checkbox4" should get enabled and others 31 checkboxes should be grey out....

Comment: Right shift and check number for being odd or even. However other thought: why don't you create a class where each property represents checkbox? That would increase your code readability.

Answer (score 2):

First convert your number to a binary string with `.toString(2)`

```
var dis = 15;
var binaryDis = dis.toString(2);
```

after that iterate through string which converted to binary; for enabling or disabling checkboxes:

```
for(var i = 0 ;i < binaryDis.length;i++)
 {
      if(binaryDis[i]==="0")
      {
         //disable your relevant checkbox 
      }
       else
      {
         //enable your relevant checkbox
      }
 }
```

Comment: I am using C language.

Comment: so ask another question and tag it as `C` not `javascript`

Comment: You consider that input is given through a  C program.

Answer (score 1):

This sets whether the checkboxes are enabled based on the bits of a 32-bit number.  It's currently set to do 15 upon page load.  Note: uses JQuery.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>binary checkboxes</title>
</head>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
$(function() {
    for(var i=0;i<32;i++) {
        $('body').append('<input type="checkbox" name="chk'+(31-i)+'" id="chk'+(31-i)+'"/>');
    }
    setboxes(15);
});

function setboxes(x) {
    for(var i=0;i<32;i++) {
        $('#chk'+i).prop('disabled',x%2===0);
        x>>=1;
    }
}
</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

It works by shifting the bits of the number to the right repeatedly and then checking if it's an even number (if the last bit is 0).

Comment: How to run this...not able to run this?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use bitwise-& like this:

```
function isCheckboxEnabled(dis, checkboxIndex) {
  return dis & Math.pow(10, checkboxIndex) > 0;
}
```

**How does it work?**

It adds your dis-value and a binary mask.

```
15|10 => 01111|2
```

If you now want to know if the first digit (the right hand one) is 1 or 0 just do it like this:

```
  01111
& 00001
-------
  00001 => 1
```

for the second one:

```
  01111
& 00010
-------
  00010 => 4
```

To enable / disable your checkboxes use something like this:

Convert you dis to binary:

```
var dis = 15;
var binaryDis = dis.toString(2);
```

Enable / Disable your Checkbox

```
for (var i = 0; i < binaryDis.length; i++)
{
   if (isCheckboxEnabled(dis, i)) {
      enableCheckbox(i);
   } else {
      disableCheckbox(i);
   }
}
```